# How to handle screen orientation problem

Tags: android, screen-orientation

In my application i am doing some process using progress bar at that time i can change the screen mode from portrait to landscape then my application is force to closed.

How to handle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't "force your application to close", it just restarts the activity.  This is the [default behaviour](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html):

> To make Android app development easier, the Android system automatically handles configuration change events and restarts the current activity with the new configuration. This is the default behavior that lets you declare resources like layouts and drawables based on the orientation, screen size, locale, etc.
>
> While this behavior is really powerful, since your application adapts automatically to the device's configuration at runtime, it is sometimes confusing for new Android developers, who wonder why their activity is destroyed and recreated.

You can, however, write your activity to declare that it can handle screen orientation changes itself.  See the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) for how to do this.